# About a bijection and inverse.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $E:= \left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | 0<x<y \right \}$ and let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} $ defined by $f(x,y)=(x+y,xy)$

Prove that $f$ is a bijection from E to $F:= \left \{ (s,t) \in \mathbb{R^2} | t>0, s>2 \sqrt{t} \right \}$ and find a formula for $f^{-1}(s,t)$

To prove that $f$ is injective I did $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ so I must conclude $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ but I entered in an infinite loop. Then, I know what a surjection is but I don't know how to prove it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Injective

Suppose f(x,y) = (x+y, xy) = (a, b); 0< x < y

$x + y = a$ so  $y = a -x.$

$  xy = xa -x^2 = b$ so $ x = \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$

so $y = \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$.  A unique solution so f is one-to-one.

Now as $0 < x < y$, $0 < \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2} < \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$ so $0 <a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b^2} < a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}$ so

$a > \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}$ so $a^2 > a^2 - 4b$ so $b > 0$.

And $ 0 <  \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}$ so $a > 2\sqrt b$.  So $(a, b) \in F$.

So $f:E \rightarrow F$ is 1-1.

2)Surjective.

For any $(a,b) \in F$, $0<\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2} < \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2} $ so $(\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}, \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}) \in E$.

$f(\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}, \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}) = (a   , b )$ so f is surjective. And $f^{-1}(a, b) = (\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}, \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2})$